# Ubuntu Live ISO booting from DVD or Pendrive: different GRUB menus

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

This is the **boot screen** (GRUB, I assume) I get if I start Ubuntu Live 14.04.2 LTS 64 bits **from DVD** (after recording the ISO):

[image: Normal Ubuntu boot]

And this one is what I get if I dump the same ISO to **pendrive** by using Universal USB Installer.

[image: Different Ubuntu boot]

I have the same behavior with Xubuntu 12.04 :

[image: Normal]

[image: Different]

**Why** is this happening? Would it generate **any problems**?

Further data:

- Some of the above examples correspond to virtual machines (Virtual Box), but I have detected this same behavior on normal computers.
- Kali Linux v2.0 does not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Startup Disk Creator, UNetbootin, Universal and others, all have different boot screens. The creators of the various USB installers would probably be in violation of copyright, (or at least good taste), if they copied each others screens exactly, even if they are open source.

I have found that some of the installers work better than others, but none have destroyed my hard drive or any USB drives yet.

Comment: So the USB boot creator program is what creates that different boot screen? I was supposing it was some UEFI/Legacy issue.